# Custom Views Filter - won't display as checkboxes

Tags: forms

Trying to do a custom filter so that the user can select multiple states to filter the data by.  This works (or will when I do some customizing to the query after) but it shows a select box.  Any ideas?  Tearing hair out :)

```
<?php
class custom_filters_handler_filter_state extends views_handler_filter_string{
  function value_form(&$form, &$form_state){
    $options = array(
     'DC' => 'DC',
     'MD' => 'MD',
     'VA' => 'VA',
    );
   $form['value'] = array(
   '#type' => 'checkboxes',
   '#title' => t('State'),
   '#multiple' => TRUE,
   '#options' => $options,
   );
return $form;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've the same issue, debugging the code I've seen that the exposed_translate() method changes any checkboxes form types to select if $form['#no_convert'] and #multiple are not set.

So you need to change it to:

```
$form['value'] = array(
   '#type' => 'checkboxes',
   '#title' => t('State'),
   '#multiple' => TRUE,
   '#options' => $options,
   '#no_convert' => TRUE,
);
```

Here is the code:

```
/**
   * Make some translations to a form item to make it more suitable to
   * exposing.
   */
  function exposed_translate(&$form, $type) {
    if (!isset($form['#type'])) {
      return;
    }

    if ($form['#type'] == 'radios') {
      $form['#type'] = 'select';
    }
    // Checkboxes don't work so well in exposed forms due to GET conversions.
    if ($form['#type'] == 'checkboxes') {
      if (empty($form['#no_convert']) || empty($this->options['expose']['multiple'])) {
        $form['#type'] = 'select';
      }
      if (!empty($this->options['expose']['multiple'])) {
        $form['#multiple'] = TRUE;
      }
    }
    if (empty($this->options['expose']['multiple']) && isset($form['#multiple'])) {
      unset($form['#multiple']);
      $form['#size'] = NULL;
    }

    // Cleanup in case the translated element's (radios or checkboxes) display value contains html.
    if ($form['#type'] == 'select') {
      $this->prepare_filter_select_options($form['#options']);
    }

    if ($type == 'value' && empty($this->always_required) && empty($this->options['expose']['required']) && $form['#type'] == 'select' && empty($form['#multiple'])) {
      $any_label = variable_get('views_exposed_filter_any_label', 'new_any') == 'old_any' ? t('<Any>') : t('- Any -');
      $form['#options'] = array('All' => $any_label) + $form['#options'];
      $form['#default_value'] = 'All';
    }

    if (!empty($this->options['expose']['required'])) {
      $form['#required'] = TRUE;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to render select elements you should extend [`views_handler_filter_in_operator`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers!views_handler_filter_in_operator.inc/class/views_handler_filter_in_operator/7) instead of `views_handler_filter_string`. I'm not aware of this, but it might be that `views_handler_filter_string` interferes with the value form in any way as to never allow multiple input or something like this.

Then, instead of defining the `value_form` on your own (which you can certainly do), you can also limit your impact and thus keep a certain configurability by overriding only the necessary class methods. In your case I would simple override [`views_handler_filter_in_operator::get_value_options`](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/handlers!views_handler_filter_in_operator.inc/function/views_handler_filter_in_operator%3a%3aget_value_options/7) like this:

```
function get_value_options() {
  if (isset($this->value_options)) {
    return;
  }
  $this->value_options = array(
    'DC' => 'DC',
    'MD' => 'MD',
    'VA' => 'VA',
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks - I had tried this option earlier and gotten an error.  Hearing from you that this was the correct approach made me take a closer look at that error.  I'm trying to do this on a field in the Location module which is causing the problem.  But, I found another solution so thank you!

Comment: @Elizabeth For future reference, can you post your solution as an answer to this question if you find the time?